# preg_replace how change part of uri

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to change all the links of a html with php preg_replace.
All the uris have the following form

```
http://example.com/page/58977?forum=60534#comment-60534
```

I want to change it to:

```
http://example.com/60534
```

which means removing everything after "page" and before "comment-", including these two strings.

I tried the following, but it returns no changes:

```
$result = preg_replace("/^.page.*.comment-.$/", "", $html);
```

but it seems that my regex syntax is not correct, as it returns the html unchanged.
Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `^` is an anchor that only matches the start of the string, and `$` only matches at the end. In order to match you should not anchor the regular expression:

```
$result = preg_replace("/page.*?comment-/", "", $html);
```

Note that this could match things that are not URLs. You may want to be more specific as to what will be replaced, for example you might want to only replace links starting with either `http:` or `https:` and that don't contain whitespace.

Comment: I have a list of urls, with a title. Something like an archive. Your code was perfect in my case. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You probably simply need this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php
This function parses a URL and returns an associative array containing any of the various components of the URL that are present.

Comment: That only works if the string itself contains a URL, not if you have to replace multiple occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way without using regular expression.

Uses `parse_url()`

```
<?php    
    $url = 'http://example.com/page/58977?forum=60534#comment-60534';
    $array = parse_url($url);
    parse_str($array['query'], $query);   
    $http = ($array['scheme']) ? $array['scheme'].'://' : NULL;    
    echo $http.$array['host'].'/'.$query['forum'];
?>
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/xB3kO588